# Combining TextViews + Image to make a full Image/file

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, layer

I have been asked to design an app that allows the user to take an image. At the top of the image there should be data such as `imageNo` and `workOrder`.

At the minute, I have two TextViews at the top of my activity, an ImageView below and then a green button at the end like so:
[ImageScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzVpV.png)

When I click the green button I would like to send this full screen, textviews and image all as one file/image to a destination - like a screenshot.

Is there any libraries out there or does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPvCEsGm8us 
check out this tutorial, I think it covers the basics of the question you asked. I automatically thought of this reference as I read your query.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I understand why you suggested this but I don't think this enables me to save or merge these as one file to be able to save it somewhere. Cool tutorial tho just made a meme app!